# Readfile from pipe blocked

Tags: delphi, readfile

In the following code, I use "commandLine" parameter to create another process, but this subprocess possibly did not write sth into pipe, so the readfile function would block.
How to let it return if there is  no data?

```
if (CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CommandLine), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup, piProcess))
  then
    sOutputString := '';
  begin

    repeat

      dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);
      Application.ProcessMessages();

    until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);

    CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);

    repeat
      dRead := 0;

      ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
      // But it is blocked......

    until (dRead < CReadBuffer);

  end;
```

Comment: This is the wrong approach anyway. Even if the other process *does* write to the pipe, your program may still get stuck. The pipe has a fixed-size buffer. If the remote process *fills* that buffer, then *it will block* until the other end of the pipe (i.e., your process) reads from the pipe and makes room for more data. Thus, you need to assure that your process won't *also* be blocked waiting for the remote process to terminate. You need to read the data *as it arrives* to keep both processes responsive.

Comment: Yes, you are very right. At first, the second repeat clause is contained in the first repeat clause.  But because I don't know how to handle the block problem, so I intend to wait for the subprocess to terminate.  This is really a mistake, and I know why now, thanks!

Comment: What pipe? Your ReadFile should return 0 immediately, you're not creating any pipe.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the named pipe contains data before reading from it

```
if PeekNamedPipe(hRead, nil, 0, nil, @dwBytesAvailable, nil) then
begin
   if dwBytesAvailable > 0 then
   begin
      ReadFile(...);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Could also `WaitForSingleObject(hReadPipe)`